# REST Service testing - SOAP UI

Tags: json, rest, soapui, payload

I need to add JSON format parameters to request payload to do a POST request in restful service testing. How can I do that in SOAP UI?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTTP GET request shouldn't contain payload. While you can do that, insofar as it isn't explicitly precluded by the HTTP specification, I would suggest avoiding it simply because people don't expect things to work that way.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is POST

Comment: Check [here](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html) good video about POST reguest parametrisation and payload.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which version of SoapUI you are using. In version 4.x of SoapUI, they made the same assumption as what FrAn answered: you generally do not want to include a payload for a GET request. In later versions of SoapUI, they corrected this and you are able to do it.

Once you change the method type to POST, on the individual method call, you will see another panel where you are able to define the body. You can see this in the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/working-with-rest-requests.html). You will have to write out the entire body manually.

For REST services, the payload is not part of the WADL - which SoapUI uses internally to store the entire definition. You can create a sample Request in your REST service to make creating test cases easier. You can see this in the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/rest-functional-testing.html).

Lastly, some additional information is available in the [API Dojo](http://www.soapui.org/testing-dojo/best-practices/testing-the-other-verbs.html).